# How to speed up scanning a big string with a big regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, performance, optimization

I have **big string**:

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec neque..."
puts string.size # => 54555999
```

I also have a **big regex**:

```
regex = /Lorem|ipsum|dolor|sit|amet|consectetur|adipiscing|elit|Donec|nec|neque|facilisis|nulla|rhoncus|accumsan|non|in|arcu|Interdum|et|malesuada|fames|ac|ante|primis|faucibus|Pellentesque|habitant|morbi|tristique|senectus|netus|turpis|egestas|at|ut|metus|convallis|fringilla|Nullam|volutpat|risus|sodales|elementum|Fusce|vitae|dignissim|tortor|Vivamus|interdum|dapibus|leo|sed|Quisque|luctus|dui|ligula|consequat|augue|congue|a|Vestibulum|id|cursus|odio|Maecenas|libero|diam|placerat|Proin|sapien|gravida|Cras|eleifend|nisl|rutrum|lectus|Curabitur|auctor|urna|tellus|tincidunt|erat|eget|vulputate|nibh|tempor|Ut|vehicula|nisi|velit|suscipit|nunc|tempus|vestibulum|viverra|Duis|sagittis|dictum|justo|hendrerit|massa|mollis|ultricies|lorem|imperdiet|mattis|pharetra|Aenean|lacus|purus|condimentum|Integer|sem|ullamcorper|feugiat|venenatis|quis|pellentesque|felis|finibus|porta|Nam|pulvinar|est|Morbi|ex|eros|commodo|Praesent|mauris|scelerisque|enim|aliquet|Etiam|Mauris|eu|bibendum|efficitur|magna|maximus|ornare|Phasellus|vel|blandit|sollicitudin|Suspendisse|Sed|quam|pretium|mi|semper|molestie|In|Nulla|Aliquam|euismod|orci|varius|hac|habitasse|platea|dictumst|iaculis|ultrices|Nunc|aliquam|fermentum|lacinia|lobortis|porttitor|laoreet|posuere|cubilia|Curae|facilisi|potenti|Cum|sociis|natoque|penatibus|magnis|dis|parturient|montes|nascetur|ridiculus|mus|Class|aptent|taciti|sociosqu|ad|litora|torquent|per|conubia|nostra|inceptos|himenaeos/
```

I now wish to `scan` the `string` with the `regex`:

```
puts Benchmark.measure { string.scan(regex) } # => 17.830000   0.380000  18.210000 ( 18.235952)
```

As you can see **scanning takes 17.83 long seconds**, and that is too much for my use case.

**How can I speed this up?**

The `match` and `=~` methods won't do me any good, because I need the array of matches. I think that maybe I need to go outside Ruby to speed this up, but I have no idea how.

The real world regex is a lot of order IDs and the real world string is a lot of emails (subject and content) merged in to one string. The point of scanning the emails for mentions of the order IDs is to find out which order IDs customers have enquired about.

**EDIT:**

The reason why I would like to make an initial regex test is because I afterwards need to make a very big loop like this:

```
["order_id_1", "order_id_2"].each do |order_id|
  ["email body 1", "email body 2"].delete_if do |email_string|
    match = (email_string =~ Regexp.new(order_id)) != nil
    if match
      # do stuff
    end
    match
    end
  end
end
```

And with many order IDs and many emails this will become a very big loop unless I initially asses which order IDs have been  corresponded about.

Comment: You should post your real-world regex... Because right now, the one one from your example, along with the input, can simply be replaced with `\p{L}+`...

Comment: Hi. The real world `regex` is a lot of order IDs and the real world `string` is a lot of emails (subject and content) merged in to one string. The point of scanning the emails for mentions of the order IDs is to find out which order IDs customers have enquired about.

Comment: Do your order IDs have a specific format (like "they always look like *1234ABC*")? In that case, write a regex for that format, and then filter them in code.

Comment: That information is helpful, Christopher. I suggest you edit your question and put it there.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, unfortunately there is is no specific pattern in the order IDs. They come from external systems and could contains both numbers and letters.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I have now added the use case description to the question.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't get the order IDs and emails in better data structures than a regex and a big string? For example, if you got both of them in lists of strings, you could then sort the strings in O(log n), then, for each email, perform a binary search on the order IDs, taking O(n log n) time altogether. That's much better than using a regex.

Comment: @Kevin, I agree, but we can let Ruby do the heavy-lifting by merely converting an array of order id's to a set.

Comment: @Kevin, I'm having a hard time following here. Would love to hear more. When you say list of strings, then what do you mean? Originally the big string is a merge of an array of emails like this: `["email body 1", "email body 2"].join(" ")`. And the order ID regex is also a merge like this: `Regexp.new(["order_id_1", "order_id_2"].join("|"))`

Comment: @Christoffer I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Christoffer, think about all the redundant computation that is happening when you make huge strings (lots of memory copying and allocation) and match them to huge regexes (the regex engine treats every character in the string as a potential starting point for a match). You should find ways (such as [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)) which [scale better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) with the size of the data.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. And thanks to the other contributors, I am looking through the answers right now.

Comment: Christopher, I think you are better off doing neither of those joins.  I expect @Kevin will agree but of course he can speak for himself. For each mail, divide the string comprising the email into words and search for those words in the collection of order ids. You'll want to the search efficiently, which means doing something like what Kevin describes (sorting the array of order ids and then using an efficient search algorithm) or converting the array to the set, in which case Ruby will do all the sorting and indexing in the background (the "heavy lifting" I mentioned).

Comment: I just posted an `O(n^2)` algorithm. I'll keep on thinking about the problem and make an edit if I can think of a more efficient way to solve the problem, but right now I have other stuff I need to get done. (The approach that I initially thought was going to be `O(n log n)` had problems when I thought about it some more.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `order_ids` is an array of order ids, which I assume contain numbers and/or digits and case is not an issue.  If `email` is a string containing one email,

```
email.scan(/\w+/) & order_ids
```

will give you all the order ids contained in that email. You can speed that up, however, by first converting `order_ids` to a set:

```
require 'set'
order_id_set = order_ids.to_set

email.scan(/\w+/).select { |w| order_id_set.include?(w) }
```

In any event, there is no advantage to stringing the emails together.

I suggested you divide the email into words using:

```
email.scan(/\w+/)
```

but you may want something more elaborate.  Suppose an email were as follows:

```
email = "I am really annoyed that my order AB123 was shipped late, " +
  "that order CD456was poorly packed and I was overcharged for order EF789."
```

Let's look at two ways we might divide this into words:

```
esplit = email.split
  #=> ["I", "am", "really", "annoyed", "that", "my", "order", "AB123",
  #    "was", "shipped", "late,", "that", "order", "CD456was", "poorly",
  #    "packed", "and", "I", "was", "overcharged", "for", "order", "EF789."]

escan = email.scan(/\w+/)
  #=> ["I", "am", "really", "annoyed", "that", "my", "order", "AB123",
  #    "was", "shipped", "late", "that", "order", "CD456was", "poorly",
  #    "packed", "and", "I", "was", "overcharged", "for", "order", "EF789"]
```

You can see trouble is brewing (e.g., `"CD456was"`) with both of these approaches. Now let's create a set of order id's:

```
require 'set'
order_id_set = %w{ AB123 CD456 EF789 GH012 }.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"AB123", "CD456", "EF789", "GH012"}>
```

and then search the email for order ids:

```
esplit.select { |w| order_id_set.include?(w) }
  #=> ["AB123"]
escan.select  { |w| order_id_set.include?(w) }
  #=> ["AB123", "EF789"]
```

As you see, `split` (same as `split(' ')` and `split(/\s+/)`), which splits the line on whitespace, caught the first order id, but missed the other two, `CD456` because the writer failed to put a space between that id and the word `"was"` and `EF789`, because it was looking for `"EF789."`.

`scan(/\w+/)`, which splits out "words" (the `\w` looks for `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`), did better, identifying `"EF789"` as an order id, because the period is a "non-word" character.  It also missed `"CD456"`, however, as `"w"`, `"a"` and `"s"` are word characters, so it included them.  (This is similar to your `"1234"` example.

What this means is the you need to craft a better regex. If, for example, all the order ids were like the ones in my example--two capital letters followed by three digits--you might write:

```
email.scan(/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{2}\d{3}(?!\d)/)
     .select { |w| order_id_set.include?(w) }
  #=> ["AB123", "CD456", "EF789"]
```

This matches two capital letters immediately preceded by anything other than a capital letter, followed by three digits, immediately followed by any character other than another digit.  This was just an illustration of what is possible.  You might want to post another question that is concerned exclusively with using regular expressions to identify possible order numbers in the emails. For that you would have to better describe what the order numbers look like, of course.

In any event, your regex would not contain `#{order_id}`, which you mentioned. The only way of doing that would be to check each email with a separate regex for each order id, which would be extraordinarily inefficient. Instead, you want to use the regex to identify *possible* order numbers and then check them against the set of order numbers. In choosing a regex you might have a tradeoff between the number of order ids that are missed and the number of non-order id strings that you waste time checking against the set of order ids.

Comment: Hi @Cary Swoveland. I have tested the method you describe, but it doesn't seem to perform so well. I created an `order_id_array` with **167282** order IDs. I then created a small `email` string with **185** characters. Here is the result from scanning the email: `puts Benchmark.measure { email.scan(/\w+/).select { |w| order_id_array.include?(w) } } # => 0.820000   0.000000   0.820000 (  0.823590)`.

Comment: Christoffer, the reason that that Cary is suggesting using a `Set` rather than an `Array` is that a set tests for inclusion by using a hash function (`Object#hash`). By using an array instead of a set for the order IDs in your benchmark, you didn't get that speed improvement.

Comment: The set isn't the issue though, the scan is. And the scan in this solution is likely to be slower because it's likely to have more matches.

Comment: @pguardiario, I agree with you that after optimizing the lookup the scan of each email will be the bottleneck. As you know, there are things that might done to reduce the number of words in the email that have to be checked against the order id collection (e.g., word length), but at some point it will be faster to just check if the word is in the collection, considering that the hash lookup will be very fast.  I think the OP should see if the execution time is satisfactory after the lookup has been speeded up, and then decide how much optimization to do with the scanning operation.

Comment: @Adrian OK I see. That did improve the performance significantly indeed. But can you explain what the `/\w+/` part of this code does? Could I replace this with another regex? My original regex was `/[\s|\W]#{order_id}[^\d]/`.

Comment: Christoffer, you need to do this: `require 'set'; order_id_set = order_id_array.to_set` and then use `order_id_set` in place of `order_id_array` in `order_id_array.include?(w)`. I think you will then find the time required to process each email is very small. Creating the set will take a bit of time, but it only has to be done once, regardless of the number of emails.

Comment: Hi @CarySwoveland. You are right. That brought up the performance significantly. But am I correct that I can then no longer search for an actual regular expression like e.g. `/[\s|\W]#{order_id}[^\d]/`?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I need to elaborate on my last comment: I can only search for the string that I want, but I can't search using a regex that excludes certain patterns, like e.g. `/[\s|\W]#{order_id}[^\d]/`, is that correct? The reason I ask is that if the `order_id` **123** was in my `order_id_array.to_set`, and an email mentioned the order ID **1234**, then a match would occur unless I search with a regex that like this one excludes any digit after the order ID.

Comment: @MarkThomas, not sure I understand. Could you put in the line of code here?

Comment: Christopher, I addressed your comment by doing an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression. Instead, use a specialized algorithm suited to the specific string and pattern you want to match. If you absolutely need to use a regular expression, you might try to find a different engine than the one that Ruby uses natively (although I doubt that this will be very fruitful). If you still need better performance, write the algorithm in a faster/lower-level language like C, and then call that from ruby with a native extension or something.

Here are some resources to help with native extensions:

- [README.EXT](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT)
- [Ruby Inline](https://github.com/seattlerb/rubyinline)
- [Ruby-FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi)

As for crafting a specialized algorithm, I probably can't help you there.

Comment: As far as I know, ruby's regex engine *is* written in c, and I think it's silly to suggest op create a native extension. Some things are just as optimized as they are going to get.

Comment: When I was a budding Rubyist I had the impression that use of regular expressions was generally accompanied by a heavy performance penalty. That may be the case in some situations, but I've seen many examples of regex's that were blazingly fast when compared to other approaches that might have been used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that runs in `O(n^2)` time. This is much better than the performance of your regex, which is likely much worse than `O(n^2)`.

The intuition behind this algorithm is that using strings and regexes is computationally expensive! Regexes are powerful tools when run over small strings or when run infrequently, but perform poorly when both the regex and string are complicated. However, in your particular case, you're not really interested in whether a string is formatted in a particular way. Instead, you want to find out which emails match which order IDs. We can do this directly, without the overhead of using regexes.

According to one of your comments, the data you receive isn't initially in the form of a long string and a long regex, but rather in two large lists. This is good, as using the lists makes it easier to use the algorithm. Since you're interested in knowing which order IDs match emails, we'll design our algorithm so that it produces an array containing every order ID that matched an email.

This is the algorthm:

1. Create an array of matched order IDs. Initially, it will be empty.
2. For each string in the array of emails,

   1. For each order ID in the array of order IDs, see if any of them match the email.
   2. If we find a match, add the order ID to the array of matched order IDs.
3. The array of matched order IDs contains every order ID that matches an email.

If there are `n` emails and `m` order IDs, this algorithm takes `O(nm)` time. If `n` and `m` are about the same, then the algorithm runs in `O(n^2)` time.

---

This is some Ruby code implementing this algorithm:

```
emails = ['email1', 'email2', 'email3', #etc.
order_ids = ['order1', 'order2', 'order3', #etc.

# Create an array to hold the matched order IDs
matched_order_ids = []

# Perform a search for each email
emails.each |email| do
  order_ids.delete_if |order_id| do
    if email.include? order_id
      matched_order_ids.push order_id

      # tells delete_if to remove the order_id,
      # saving us time searching in future emails
      return true
    else
      # tells delete_if not to remove the order_id
      return false
    end
  end
end

# At this point, matched_order_ids contains every
# order ID that was matched in at least one of the
# emails
```

Comment: This is slightly off topic, but `return` can only return from methods, not blocks. :)

Comment: @Andrian, need to check that. :-)